# Java Swing Simple Split Panel GUI

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Im trying to make a simple split-panel java GUI, where the left side has a custom drawing, and the right side has a button, controls etc. However, when I run the code, the drawing does not appear. Not sure if I am actually setting up the panels correctly as well.

```
public class windowBuild extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public windowBuild() {
        myPanel panel = new myPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        JPanel panelOne = new JPanel();
        JPanel panelTwo = new JPanel();

        panelTwo.add(new JLabel("2"));

        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        container.add(panel);
        container.add(panelTwo);

        this.add(container);
    }

    class myPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fill3DRect(10, 10, 10, 10, true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new windowBuild();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a `BorderLayout`?  It can be funny to work with, and you're not using any of its features.

Comment: Also: this code appears to work for me: when run I see a red square on the left and the number 2 on the right.  What were you expecting to be different?

Comment: 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2) `class myPanel extends JPanel {` should override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method rather than paint, should immediately call the super method when custom painting, and most importantly, should override the `getPreferredSize()` method to define a sensible value for use by a layout manager. Then `this.setSize(500, 500);` should be removed and instead use `pack()`..

Comment: I agree with most of Andrews points, except for `setSize()` vs. `pack()`.  For a top level window (which in this case is the `JFrame` the OP is using) it makes more sense to set a "user friendly" size.  This is rarely the size set by `pack()`, which scrunches everything up as much as possible.  Although I think `setMinimumSize()` would actually be a better choice still, allowing the window to expand if needed.

Comment: One thing that does irk me is that you call `new windowBuild()` directly from the main thread.  Swing is multithreaded and its components should only be invoked by the EDT.  Please switch the call in `main` to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater( windowBuild::new );`  Read up on Swing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, I went through and corrected. It looks like one major issue I was having was calling the `new windowBuild()` directly from the main thread that @markspace mentioned. The image wasn't loading until I manually resized window. I was also attempting to add a border around each panel to separate, would this be accomplished by `this.add(panelTwo, BorderLayout.EAST);` ?

Comment: You're using a grid layout; why would adding a border to the BorderLayout do anything?  You can just add borders to the components themselves if you have to, though it sounds like you want to use a JPanel instead.  C.f. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html